# How to calculate the perimeter of a binary image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to perform feature extraction on an image for a program I am working on, currently I can calculate the area of this but am having trouble with the perimeter.

How could I implement this in order to return a numeric value for the perimeter using java?

Thanks,

Tom

```
        Raster raster = source.getRaster();
    int perimeter = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y<source.getHeight(); y++)
        for(int x = 0; x< source.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            if(raster.getSample(x, y, 0) == 1 && ((raster.getSample(x+1, y, 0)==0) || (raster.getSample(x-1, y, 0)==0) || (raster.getSample(x, y+1, 0)==0) || (raster.getSample(x, y-1, 0)==0)))
                perimeter ++;
        }
    return perimeter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an approach similar to Matlab (described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwperim.html))

> A pixel is part of the perimeter if it
>   is nonzero and it is connected to at
>   least one zero-valued pixel

You can define various neighbourhoods for the pixels (e.g. a surrounding grid of three, or just up/down/left/right).  Once you've filtered the image, counting the pixels out to give you a value.

Comment: "connected to at least one zero-valued pixel"  - Your example code didn't seem to do quite that.  I added an example

Comment: this gives me a huge number, way more than the actual value whereas my previous code seems to work fine

Comment: Maybe my pseudo-code was rubbish, I'll remove it and just leave the link to the Matlab documentation as that seems more useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an example of this and making one could take a while, but you could take a look at the [marching squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) -algorithm.

Edit: [here](http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/marching-squares)'s an implementation of Marching Squares written in Java by Tom Gibara.